# Liquid Tag in Where Filter in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, where-clause

The following:

`{% assign devices = site.data.equipment | where:"department","sound" | group_by:"servicelocation" %}`

Is helping me build a list of sound devices from the equipment data list, grouped by location.  The file resides in the `_includes` folder and is entitled `equipment_list.html.`

When I include this file in a `_page`, it displays exactly what I need, but I am attempting to take it one step further.

`{% assign departmentname = page.name | remove:"equipment_list_" | remove:".md" %}` yields the word `sound` based upon the `_page/equipment_list_sound.md` file.

`{{ departmentname }}` = "sound" as expected.

Can I insert this value into the `where` filter somehow to be able to re-use the equipment list page over and over again for different departments?

`where:"department","{{departmentname}}"` fails, and any variation I can imagine also fails.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : `{% assign devices = site.data.equipment | where:"department", departmentname | group_by:"servicelocation" %}`

Comment: Holy cow.  I swear I tried that and it didn't work.  I started writing some if/thens to handle it, but I tried exactly your syntax and it worked!  Good grief.  Thanks!